# Get data from model A to model B after filling the form of model B in django

Tags: django, django-models, copy, django-admin

I have following two models. What I want is Whenever I fill the data in model Book i.e its name (like name of Book says Java) It will automatically be saved also in Contributor model under field "name". Also I can manually be able to fill the "name" field in Contributor model in django Admin

```
class Book(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Contributor(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

[Data in model Book](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lyYZi.png)
[After Filling Data in model Book I want Data in model Contributor as this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aC3Xl.png)

Comment: You can override the save method of Book model, or better write a post_save signal for Book model.

Comment: It basically depends on how your form looks like and what you want to achieve with the writing the data in another model. Do you want to create a `Contributor` when creating a `Book` or do you only want to create it if the `Contributor` didn't exist before? Additional Question, why do you need to create an instance of an model that is not linked with a ForeignKey?

Comment: I want to create a Contributor when creating a Book. Also I want to add data with Contributor  model

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question clearly, you want to link a **Book** to its **Contributor**. Just use the `ForeignKey` method. By doing this, a **Book** object will contain all information about its **Contributor** (not just its name).

```
class Book(models.Model):
    contributor = models.ForeignKey(Contributor, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.contributor.name

class Contributor(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

All about ForeignKey in Django is [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/examples/many_to_one/).